# ALTERAÇÃO E LEITURA DE DIRETÓRIOS EM C#

Tags: c#, txt, path, xpath, app.config

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em C#, que utiliza scripts em python como motor (Não utilizei IronPython devido as suas limitações, eu trabalho com pandas), o que faço é simplesmente executar o script através de um PROCESS no c#, passando qual o diretório do python.exe e qual o diretório do script que quero executar, EXEMPLO:

```
    private void ExecutarScript()
    {
        this.bnt_ExecutarScript.Enabled = false;

        string p_cmd = @"C:\Users\dalton.takeuchi\Anaconda3\python.exe";
        string file = @"C:\PROJETO 11\Python\VMN\VMN.py";

        run_script(p_cmd, file);

        this.CarregarGridSimulacao();
        this.bnt_ExecutarScript.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void run_script(string p_cmd, string file)
    {
        if (processoEmExecucao == false)
        {
            try
            {
                processoEmExecucao = true;
                p_cmd = string.Format(@"'{0}'", p_cmd).Replace("'", "\"");
                file = string.Format(@"'{0}'", file).Replace("'", "\"");

                ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo(p_cmd, file);
                start.UseShellExecute = false;
                start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                start.CreateNoWindow = true;

                using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
                {
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    /*
                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                    {
                        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        //MessageBox.Show(result," PYTHON]:",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    */
                }
            }

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                processoEmExecucao = false;

            }
        }
    }
```

O problema é que não posso deixar esses diretórios, tanto do python quanto dos scripts como algo fixo no sistema, por que assim eles irão dar problema em outras máquinas...

Vocês poderiam me indicar uma forma de configurar os diretórios para cada instalação de uma forma que não seja manual? pensei em utilizar um txt para armazenar os diretórios e ler direto dele... é facil editar um txt e iria acabar com o problema, mas estou tendo dificuldades com isso também. Preciso saber o diretório do txt para que possa ler e editá-lo...

Desde já, agradeço!

Comment: Veja o meu comentário na sua pergunta original.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [ARQUIVOS EM DIRETÓRIOS C# + PYTHON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328873/arquivos-em-diret%c3%93rios-c-python)

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução viável seria a leitura do PATH da instalação do Python.

O seu programa teria um pré-requisito que seria o python instalado, e a partir disso você conseguiria fazer a leitura do path de instalação do python.

O path de instalação estaria nas variáveis de ambiente.

Então no lugar de você exigir que seja adicionado o caminho em um txt, você simplesmente faria a leitura do path de instalação.

Caso isso não seja possível, bastaria você fazer a leitura manual do diretório de instalação, nesse caso ficaria estático o caminho de instalação padrão do python.

Answer (score 0):

Dá uma olhada nesse código.

Basicamente faz o que você sugeriu: Cria um arquivo de configuração e, caso exista, apenas o lê e os valores são retornados nas variáveis comentadas abaixo.

```
    private void GetPath()
    {
        // Diretório do programa (C#)
        string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        if (File.Exists(appPath + @"\config.ini"))
        {
            //                          Referência: System.IO
            string[] getConfigContent = File.ReadAllLines(appPath + @"\config.ini");

            // Seu código...
            // getConfigContent[0] = Primeiro diretório
            // getConfigContent[1] = Segundo diretório
        }
        else
        {
            string[] setConfigContent = new string[2];
            setConfigContent[0] = "Path1"; // Primeiro diretório
            setConfigContent[1] = "Path2"; // Segundo diretório

            File.WriteAllLines(appPath + @"\config.ini", setConfigContent);
        }
    }
```